# Do scratches decrease UV protection?

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, visible-light

Some scratches have appeared out of nowhere on my new running sunglasses, slightly damaging its mirror coating.

Do scratches on sunglasses decrease its UV protection, or is the UV protection somehow inherent of the material?

Comment: Don't know if there is a general answer to your question or not. May depend on the manufacturer of the sunglasses. I would just try to contact the sunglass maker and ask them whether the UV protection is in the lens or whether it is applied as a coating.

Answer (score 0):

The coating should act as a filter for the UV rays, however, some scratches shouldn't significantly affect the total amount of UV rays penetrating.

Although I believe you can and should contact the manufacturer and see if they will exchange for a new one! :)